# urls amigables nginx con parametros

Tags: php, url, nginx

Estoy tratando de cambias mis url de forma dinamica pero no me permite acceder a ellas.

**Url actual:**
http://dominio.com/?ruta=usuarios
**Url amigable:**
http://dominio.com/usuarios

**Archivo de configuracion esto en nginx**

```
    location / {
       try_files $uri/ /?ruta=$args; **no funciona**
        try_files $uri $uri/ /?ruta=$args; **no funciona**
   }
```

**Funciona pero deficientemente**

```
   location / {
            root www/app;
            if (!-e $request_filename) {
                    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /?ruta=$1 last;
            }
    }
```

Alguien que me pudiera apoyar en este apartado, muchas gracias!

Comment: vamos a ver como te ayudamos haca dame unos minutos que me hace falta investigar algo sobre ***rewrite***

Answer (score 0):

Para implementar URLs amigables, puedes utilizar la directiva `rewrite` en conjunto con una `expresión regular`.

Ejemplo de cómo configurar Nginx para manejar URLs amigables con parámetros:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
}

location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?ruta=$1 last;
}
```

con esta implementacion asumimos que tienes un archivo `index.php` para las rutas.

La configuración anterior indica que si Nginx no encuentra una coincidencia directa para la URL solicitada, intentará reescribir la URL utilizando la expresión regular `^/(.*)$`. Luego, redirige la solicitud a `index.php` con el parámetro ruta correspondiente.

Asegúrate de ajustar la ruta del archivo `index.php` y la ubicación en la que se encuentra en tu servidor.

Recuerda:

- Reinicia el servidor para que los cambios surtan efecto.
- Después de eso, deberías poder acceder a URLs amigables como:
  http://dominio.com/usuarios
  y Nginx redirigirá internamente la solicitud a:
  http://dominio.com/index.php?ruta=usuarios.

A mi me paso algo similar pero en apache.